# SQLite in-memory database for multiple connections

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, phpunit

My application has to use two database connections, called `mysql` and `mysql_tenant`. The User model is on the first connection and the Company model is on the second one.

There's a relationship between the two, a Company belongsToMany Users. The relationship uses the `company_user` pivot table that is stored on the `mysql_tenant` database.

The relationship is defined like this :

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'demo_tenant.company_user');
}
```

In this case, **demo_tenant** is the name of the second database, as defined in my ENV file.

This works great, except when it comes to testing. I'm using PHPUnit and setting the DB_DRIVER to **sqlite** and the DB_DATABASE to **:memory:** so that the test runs faster and don't hit the actual MySQL databases.

When I run the test, the code fails when it tries to access the `demo_tenant` database because the name is replaced by `:memory:` for the sake of the tests.

I tried to replace the hardcoded value with something more dynamic :

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, env('DB_DATABASE_TENANT') . '.company_user');
}
```

However, this still fails when the tests run with the following error :

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: :memory:.company_user

How can I make the in-memory databases work with multiple connections? Is there a way to give each of them a unique name?

Here is my `phpunit.xml` for reference :

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>

    <env name="DB_DRIVER" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <env name="DB_DRIVER_TENANT" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE_TENANT" value=":memory:"/>
</php>
```

Comment: Laravel relations translate to joins in the generated queries. You can not join a table through a second connection.

If this works outside of tests, it only works because both databases are actually reachable through the same connection.

Comment: Hey! Did you find a solution for this?